# Power Automate does not show dynamic content of adaptive card

Tags: power-automate, adaptive-cards

My project is about confirming the data of new employees and visitors and confirming if they need photo permission for construction work.
This data is stored on a Sharepoint list, which should be confirmed after creation.
I want to create a workflow using power Automate. Now I've written an adaptive card for it. I want to access what (submit.)action was taken and this is in my case:

- approve
- approve visit and deny photo permission
- correct
- refuse

Before all actions except approve, there are Input.Texts that I want to access as well.
As far as I know, this data can be accessed using dynamic contents. Now there is no dynamic content for the adaptive card.

Is there another way to access the adaptive card response?

For the completeness of this question and in case the error is in my (slightly longer) JSON file, you can see it here:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "Confirmation of a visitor registration"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "style": "Person",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_B%C3%BCrogeb%C3%A4ude_--_2013_--_5149-51.jpg/1280px-M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_B%C3%BCrogeb%C3%A4ude_--_2013_--_5149-51.jpg"
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "auto",
                    "backgroundImage": {
                        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_B%C3%BCrogeb%C3%A4ude_--_2013_--_5149-51.jpg/1280px-M%C3%BCnster%2C_LVM%2C_B%C3%BCrogeb%C3%A4ude_--_2013_--_5149-51.jpg"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "text": "Campus Access",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "spacing": "None",
                            "text": "Created {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:08:39Z,SHORT)}}",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "width": "stretch"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "wrap": true,
            "text": "Hello,\n\nYou have been selected as the main contact(s) for an upcoming visit.\nPlease confirm the visit of the following person and the correctness of the information:",
            "spacing": "Medium"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "General information about the visit",
            "wrap": true,
            "fontType": "Default",
            "color": "Accent",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "separator": true,
            "spacing": "Medium"
        },
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "title": "company:",
                    "value": "dyin1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "visitor:",
                    "value": "dyin2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "visitor's E-Mail:",
                    "value": "dyin3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "registration reason:",
                    "value": "dyin4"
                },
                {
                    "title": "visit period:",
                    "value": "dyin5"
                }
            ],
            "spacing": "None",
            "separator": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "There is also information about a photo permit:",
            "wrap": true,
            "spacing": "Medium",
            "weight": "Default",
            "fontType": "Default",
            "color": "Default"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Information about a photo permit",
            "wrap": true,
            "separator": true,
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "color": "Accent",
            "spacing": "Medium"
        },
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "title": "Photo permission required:",
                    "value": "dyin6"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Reason for photo permission:",
                    "value": "dyin7"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Restriction of photo permission:",
                    "value": "dyin8"
                }
            ],
            "id": "fotoerlaubnisDaten",
            "spacing": "None",
            "separator": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "If the visit and the general data as well as the photo permission data are correct, please click on \"Approve\".\n\nIf you want to approve the visit, but the answer to \"Need photo permission\" is yes and this photo permission must be denied, click \"Approve visit and deny photo permission\".\n\nIf this data needs to be corrected, please do so under \"correct\".",
            "wrap": true,
            "spacing": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "approve",
                    "style": "positive"
                }
            ],
            "id": "genehmigen"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                    "title": "approve visit and deny photo permission",
                    "targetElements": [
                        "GrundVerweigerung",
                        "genehmigtFotoverweigert_ende"
                    ],
                    "id": "genehmigtFotoverweigert"
                }
            ],
            "id": "genehmigtFotoverweigtert",
            "spacing": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "reason for refusal",
            "id": "GrundVerweigerung",
            "label": "Please provide a reason for refusing photo permission. The visitor will be informed of your reason:",
            "isVisible": false
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Visit finally approved and photo permission denied",
                    "style": "destructive"
                }
            ],
            "id": "genehmigtFotoverweigert_ende",
            "isVisible": false
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                    "title": "correct",
                    "targetElements": [
                        "Containerkorrigieren",
                        "Erklärung",
                        "NötigGrund",
                        "BefristungFoto",
                        "korrigiertgenehmigt"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "id": "korrigieren",
            "spacing": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                                    "columns": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "Column",
                                            "width": "stretch",
                                            "items": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                                    "placeholder": "please correct here",
                                                    "label": "company:",
                                                    "id": "KorrekturFirma"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "type": "Column",
                                            "width": "stretch",
                                            "items": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                                    "placeholder": "please correct here",
                                                    "label": "visitor:",
                                                    "id": "KorrekturBesucher"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                                    "columns": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "Column",
                                            "width": "stretch",
                                            "items": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                                    "placeholder": "please correct here",
                                                    "label": "visitor's E-Mail:",
                                                    "id": "KorrekturMail"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                    "placeholder": "please correct here",
                                    "label": "registration reason:",
                                    "id": "KorrekturAnmeldegrund"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "ColumnSet",
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "id": "hier",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.Date",
                                    "label": "Visit start date:",
                                    "id": "KorrekturStart"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Column",
                            "width": "stretch",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Input.Date",
                                    "label": "Visit end date:",
                                    "id": "KorrekturEnde"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "isVisible": false,
            "id": "Containerkorrigieren",
            "spacing": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "please correct here",
                            "label": "Photo permission required:",
                            "id": "Fotoerlaubnisnötig"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Input.Text",
                            "placeholder": "please correct here",
                            "id": "GrundFotoerlaubnis",
                            "label": "Reason for photo permission:"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "isVisible": false,
            "id": "NötigGrund"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Date",
            "id": "BefristungFoto",
            "label": "Restriction of photo permission:",
            "isVisible": false,
            "spacing": "None"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "corrected and approved"
                }
            ],
            "id": "korrigiertgenehmigt",
            "isVisible": false
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "In the following you can refuse the visit.",
            "wrap": true,
            "spacing": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                    "title": "refuse",
                    "targetElements": [
                        "GrundAblehnung",
                        "endgültigablehnen"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "id": "ablehnen",
            "spacing": "Large"
        },
        {
            "type": "Input.Text",
            "placeholder": "reason for rejection",
            "label": "Please describe the reason for the rejection. The rejected visitor will be informed of your reason.",
            "id": "GrundAblehnung",
            "isVisible": false
        },
        {
            "type": "ActionSet",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "final refuse",
                    "style": "destructive"
                }
            ],
            "id": "endgültigablehnen",
            "isVisible": false
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.3"
}
```

Comment: Are you using "Post adaptive card and wait for a response" action? Try [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-to-collect-responses-with-adaptive-cards-on-microsoft-teams/), [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Dynamic-content-missing-from-quot-Post-adaptive-card-and-wait/td-p/1475046) and [this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Post-adaptive-card-with-dynamic-content/td-p/464396). Let me know if it works.

Comment: I saw under this link that after "post adaptive card and wait for a response" the IDs are displayed as dynamic content. The author of the article used the acPollChoices ID to access the answer:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-to-collect-responses-with-adaptive-cards-on-microsoft-teams/

However, in my case, the IDs are not displayed as dynamic content at all.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is a Dynamic Content for the "Post adaptive card and wait for a response" action in Power Automate, please see the following pic :

[image]
[image]

→ so to access the adaptive card response you use simply use "**submitActionId**" on your next action inside your Workflow. That's it !

Cordially.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Sorry, I didn't quite understand your suggestion.

Should I include "submitActionID" in the adaptive card?

I saw under this link that after "post adaptive card and wait for a response" the IDs are displayed as dynamic content. The author of the article used the acPollChoices ID to access the answer:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-to-collect-responses-with-adaptive-cards-on-microsoft-teams/

However, in my case, the IDs are not displayed as dynamic content at all.